# How does one use the Google Play Developer API to "Start rollout to internal testing"?

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I'm using the Google Play Developer API to PUBLISH my bundle to our INTERNAL testing track, but it doesn't publish it all the way. I still have to manually go to the Play Console and click on "Start rollout to internal testing".

Is there a way to have it FULLY publish the app bundle?